# Flutter Bloc State Only Updates Once

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

The problem is that I would like to show a loading indicator when the user tries to fetch some data from an api. But when the user presses the button, loading indicator shows once. But I would like to show the loading indicator every time when the user tries to fetch. It works but as I say It works once. Could anyone have any idea what can cause this problem? Here's the minimal code to reproduce the issue:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(create: (_) => HomeCubit()),
      ],
      child: const MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Bloc Demo',
        home: HomeView(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeView extends BaseView<HomeCubit, HomeState> {
  const HomeView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget builder(HomeCubit cubit, HomeState state) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text(state.count.toString()),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: cubit.increment,
            child: const Text('Increase'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeState extends BaseState {
  final int count;

  HomeState({required this.count});

  HomeState copyWith({
    int? count,
  }) {
    return HomeState(
      count: count ?? this.count,
    );
  }
}

class HomeCubit extends BaseCubit<HomeState> {
  HomeCubit() : super(HomeState(count: 0));

  void increment() {
    flow(() async {
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));

      emit(state.copyWith(count: state.count + 1));
    });
  }
}

@immutable
abstract class BaseView<C extends StateStreamable<S>, S extends BaseState>
    extends StatelessWidget {
  const BaseView({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) {
        return BaseCubit(context.read<S>());
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: BlocBuilder<C, S>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            final cubit = context.read<C>();

            if (state.loadingState == LoadingState.loading) {
              return loadingWidget;
            }

            return builder.call(cubit, state);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget builder(C cubit, S state);

  Widget get loadingWidget => const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
}

enum LoadingState { initial, loading, loaded }

class BaseState {
  LoadingState loadingState;

  BaseState({
    this.loadingState = LoadingState.initial,
  });
}

class BaseCubit<S extends BaseState> extends Cubit<S> {
  BaseCubit(S state) : super(state);

  Future<void> flow(Future<void> Function() function) async {
    state.loadingState = LoadingState.loading;
    emit(state);

    await function();

    state.loadingState = LoadingState.loaded;
    emit(state);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

1. Is it overengineering? I don't think you are duplicating much code if you just use BlocBuilder instead of some base class.
2. If bloc already exist you should provide it by BlocProvider.value instead of BlocProvider(create: read())
3. You should use context.watch instead of context.read to get a new value every time the state changes. context.read receives state only once.
4. It's overengineering, please take a look at https://bloclibrary.dev/#/coreconcepts. There are enough tutorials to catch the basic idea.
5. Then try to use bloc + freezed. Here is an example https://dev.to/ptrbrynt/why-bloc-freezed-is-a-match-made-in-heaven-29ai

Comment: OP didn't ask anything about overengineering nor anything about other types of solutions.